# Graphical output in the console window. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to draw a rectangle (background) and a line in the console window. When I run my program, nothing happens in the console window. How do I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HDC hDC;
    HWND hWnd;
    RECT Rect;
    HPEN hPen;
    hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
    Rectangle(hDC, 500, 500, 500, 500);
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    MoveToEx(hDC, 10, 10, NULL);
    LineTo(hDC, 100, 100);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    _getch();
}
```

I tried to find a solution, maybe a problem with WinAPI.

Comment: I suspect you are not allowed to draw in console windows because console windows have higher security privilege (for historical reasons)

Comment: Your code runs fine on my Windows 10 machine. Tell us more about your compiler/IDE/environnment/platform/...

Comment: ...but `Rectangle(hDC, 500, 500, 500, 500)` will draw a rectangle of size 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I use Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022, ISO C MSVC

Comment: @IvanovVladislav pretty much the same as here except I have W10 and you have W11. Can't check on W11 right now...

Comment: Works fine for me in Windows 10. *shrug*

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work anymore on W11.

Comment: Maybe instead of ::GetConsoleWindow, you should use [::CreateWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa). In the end it is more common to draw to a memory bitmap and blit that in the OnPaint method of a window of your own (so it gets redrawn after being occluded or min/maxing the window)

Comment: Works for me on windows 10 in the console but not in the new windows terminal

Comment: If you draw into a window that isn't yours, then the results are unpredictable. (And the console window isn't yours. It's owned by the console system. After all, the console system is going to draw into it too, and you have no way to coordinate your drawing with the console's drawing.)

Comment: for what you need console window and separate console process ? create own window and draw here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the Blog:[Windows Terminal is now the Default in Windows 11](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/)

As far as I'm concerned, That's why it works well on win10 and doesn't work on W11.

I suggest you could try to change your terminal to `Windows Console Host` in the settings:

[image]

Result：

[image]

Comment: *"That's why it works well on win10"* - It doesn't *"work well"*, by any stretch of the term, on **any** version of Windows. You cannot render into any window you do not own, reliably, without that window providing a way to coordinate painting. The window returned from `GetConsoleWindow()` doesn't.